# In Pentaho data integration how to apply row_number() over (partition by category order by storename) rownumbers logic to the rows

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I just want to assign row numbers for similar kind of rows [enter image description here]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyLpT.png)

I am trying to assign row number for similar kind of rows in pentaho data integration

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Add value fields changing sequence` step to assign the row number of each group and don't forget to add the `Sort rows` step before assigning the value

[image: demo]